# Find all value of $z$ for which each equation holds.

Tags: complex-analysis

$$(a) \sin z=\cosh 4$$

$$(b) \cos z=2$$

$$(c) \sin z=i\sinh 1$$

$$(d) \cosh z=1$$

**my answer**

(a) $\sin z= \sin x \cosh y+\cos x \sinh y=\cosh 4$

so, $x=2n\pi+{\pi\over2}$ and $y=4$

(b) since maximum value of $\cos z$ is 1, so DNE.

(c) represent, $-e^{iz}+e^{-iz}=e-e^{-1}$

ie) $-e^{-y}(\cos x+i\sin x)+e^y(\cos x-i\sin x)=e-e^{-1}$

then $y=1$ and $x=2n\pi$

(d) $e^x(\cos x+i\sin y)+e^{-x}(\cos x-i\sin y)=2$

ie) $\cos y(e^x+e^{-x})+i\sin y(e^x-e^{-x})=2$

then $y=2n\pi$ and x=0.

$ $

Could you check my answer? and please edit it.

Comment: Be coherent. If (a) has a solution, so does (b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are really simple to solve, if thought about in the right way. We only need one fact, $$e^{z}=e^{w}\ \ \ \ \ \text{if and only if}\ \ \ \ \ z-w=2\pi i n\ \ \ \ \ \text{for some}\ \ \ \ \ n\in\mathbb{Z}.$$ Consider case two, $$\cos(z)=2.$$ Write, $$\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}=2,$$ cancel  fractions, $$(2e^{iz})\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}= (2e^{iz})2,$$ isolate the quadratic, $$(e^{iz})^2-4e^{iz}+1=0,$$ solve the quadratic, $$e^{iz}=2\pm \sqrt{3}=e^{\ln(2\pm\sqrt{3})},$$ hence, $$zi-\ln(2\pm \sqrt{3})=2\pi i n,$$ thus, $$z=-\ln(2\pm\sqrt{3})i+2\pi n.$$ These are all the solutions and the only solutions for $\cos(z)=2$. Compare with [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Roots%20cos%28z%29=2). Notice all the answers are non-real, this follows because (like you said) $-1\le \cos(r)\le 1$ holds for all real numbers. In general, all answers to trigonometric functions look like $\theta+2\pi n$ for some angle $\theta$. For hyper-trigonometric functions all answers look like $\theta+2\pi i n$ for some angle $\theta$. When solving Trigonometric or hyper-trigonometric equations, it is always best to use the exponential definitions, because of the property mention at the top. In this way, all these problems can be similarly solved.

Answer (score 0):

$(d)\displaystyle\cosh(z)=1\implies\cos(iz)=1=\cos0\implies iz=2n\pi$ where $n$ is any integer

$(b)$  $-1\le\cos z\le1$ for real $z$ only

$(a)\displaystyle\sin z=\cosh4=\cos(4i)=\sin\left(\frac\pi2-4i\right)$

$\displaystyle z=n\pi+(-1)^n\left(\frac\pi2-4i\right)$

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use general formulas for the inverse trigonometric functions, together with the periodicity of the complex logarithm. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Inverse_functions_as_logarithms, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Hyperbolic_functions_for_complex_numbers,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm.